# Unsure of the meaning of ‘secure’ and ‘return’ in: ‘its object was…to secure her from any return of Mr Collins’s addresses…’

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

The full quote from Jane Austen’s Pride and Prejudice is as follows:

> This was very amiable, but Charlotte's kindness extended farther than Elizabeth had any conception of;— its object was nothing less, than to secure her from any return of Mr. Collins's addresses, by engaging them towards herself.

I’m not really sure what the quote as a whole means. I’m guessing here that Charlotte is sensible to Mr Collins’s advances and ‘addresses’, and consequently hopes to ensure his favour by acting in a way that maintains his attention and prevents his rescinding his ‘addresses’. So, ‘to secure her from’ is essentially ‘to secure against’? Since the former is not often used in a modern context, I think. And then the ‘return of Mr Collins’s addresses’ would mean his taking back his interest in Charlotte, which she seeks to prevent by ‘engaging them towards herself’ — i.e. hogging his attention(?). I would really appreciate some clarification on whether this is correct or not.

Thank you.

Comment: "to relieve from exposure to danger : act to make safe against adverse contingencies" is an absolutely standard dictionary meaning of [secure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secure), and Merriam-Webster has "from enemy raids" as an example.

Comment: If you're going to read 200-year-old prose in public, please get a good dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charlotte is planning to prevent Mr Collins from taking any more romantic interest in Elizabeth by attracting his attention towards herself (Charlotte). '*Return of* his addresses' just means a repetition of them.

Comment: Thank you! So I would like to clarify that the quote can be understood as: “…its object was nothing less, than to relieve her from any exposure to the danger of any repetition of Mr. Collins's addresses (towards Elizabeth), by engaging them (instead) towards herself.”?

Comment: In effect, yes.